# Is it fine for a process to switch to non-existent user?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

Consider the following code, which is a simplification of [ncopa/su-exec](https://github.com/ncopa/su-exec/blob/master/su-exec.c)

```c
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <assert.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

uid_t parse_uid(const char *arg)
{
    assert(arg[0] != '\0');

    char *end;
    uid_t uid = strtol(arg, &end, 10);
    assert(*end == '\0');

    return uid;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3)
        return 1;

    uid_t uid = parse_uid(argv[1]);
    if (setuid(uid) < 0)
        err(1, "setuid(%i)", uid);

    setenv("HOME", "/", 1);

    char **cmdargv = &argv[2];
    execvp(cmdargv[0], cmdargv);
    err(1, "%s", cmdargv[0]);

    return 1;
}
```

It can switch to any non-existent user by:

```
sudo ./a.out 65535 sleep 10m
```

and you can find the process `sleep 10m` of user id `65535` in `ps` or `htop`.

Though the kernel didn't complain about anything, but I doubt it is a piece of legal code, since it switched to a user never exist.

Comment: root is allowed to do things other users are not (basically, root is special).

Comment: It's fine.  The new user may not be able to do much (because it won't own much to start with — though it will be able to do what the general public can do, of course).  There's no list of valid user IDs in the kernel — any number is as good as any other, regardless of whether the password file knows about it.

Comment: So from the point of the kernel, it is completely fine, but what about other components from the user space? Can they play with non-existence user?

Comment: It depends.  Programs like `ls` will list the number instead of (non-existent) name for the UID of files owned by (created by) the UID.  Some programs may get upset if the UID is not recognized, but they really shouldn't.  If you import a tar file from some other machine, it may have UIDs and GIDs that have no name or other existence on you machine.  If you import as root, those non-existent IDs may be used on the extracted files.  As a mortal user, there's no issue — the files become yours.

Comment: It's interesting to speculate what happens if you have a user entry in the password file with an all-numeric user name and a different UID (`1234:x:4321:9876:Who:/home/where:/bin/bash`) — especially if there's a complementary pair (`4321:x:1234:6789:Noone:/home/noone:/bin/bash`).  How do you get to interpret what's presented?  I'm not aware of anything that stops this happening, though it is undoubtedly a horrible way to build a password database.

Comment: I've seen group files, in particular, with multiple entries with the same name and different group numbers, and multiple entries with the same group number and different names — because there was a 512 byte limit on lists of names in groups. Anything longer corrupted the data files.  Who is a member of group `common`?  Who is a member of the group with GID 5432?  What is the name of the group with GID 5432?  What is the GID of the group named `common`?  There usually isn't a formally specified set of rules, so it tends to be a bit hit and miss, depending on which software wants to do what.

Comment: Sounds like linux user/group management can really be a mess...